# allocating Memory to the variable which has been already allocated?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I want to allocate memory for the variable to which i have allocated already.for example

```
        self.m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];
```

I have to change assigned view controller for above tabbar controller.so i have to release
the above and allocate the same tabbar  with new controllers. how can I release and allocate 
new one.If i do the following, gives crashes.

```
  if(self.m_tabbarController != nil)
    {
      [self.m_tabbarController release];    
    }
             self.m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];
```

but self variable must be deallcated in dealloc method.any help please?if i do like following also, it gives crash?

```
   m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:m_tabbarController ];
     [m_tabbarController release];
```

Answer (score 2):

First release it. Assuming your synthesised property is `retain`, the implementation will handle the `release` for you:

```
self.m_tabbarController = [[[TabbarController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

In short, you cannot rely on some way to reinitialize an instance unless you implement some kind of reinitialization method in the class.

If that's a `UIViewController`, just create a new `UIViewController` because you would need to know a lot about an implementation, all subclasses, and all members/ivars to implement reinitialization correctly. Sometimes you can accomplish this via its public properties, sometimes you won;t be able to reinitialize an instance correctly.

One problem with reinitialization is that what you `alloc` may not be what's returned -- and you may not otherwise know what type you are dealing with specifically in all cases. Proper, exhaustive reimplementation of a complex type adds a lot of implementation (which tends to be transitive too).

Comment: Setting the property to `nil` before assigning a new value is completely superfluous.

Comment: @Justin, you solution is absolutely right. But I suggest this scenario should avoid using `autorelease`. Instead of using `autorelease`, use `release` after assigned the value to property.

Comment: @Tonny Xu In this case, something is wrong with the design if the view controller were *not* to outlive the local autorelease pool. Thus, the view controller that has yet to be displayed is a safe thing to `autorelease` because it will outlive the local autorelease pool -- would you disagree, or did you make the suggestion for another reason?

Comment: @Justin, Hmm, I don't understand what you mean **local autorelease pool** here. This `self` should be some kind of class lives in main thread, and because the `main()` has created an autorelease pool for **main thread**. I don't think @nameless has created another *local autorelease pool* for reinitialize the `tabbarController` instance. So it's a simple problem on how to assign a value to the property correctly. And as Apple mentioned in it's document, avoid using `autorelease` if the property is set to `retain` or `copy`. As I said, your solution is correct. I just did a little suggestion;)

Comment: @Tonny Xu yes - autorelease pools can be created like stacks (push+pop, they're thread local). it's certainly possible for a thread to have more than one autorelease pool. by 'local', i mean the one on the top of the stack of the current thread. there's a likely a design flaw if the new view controller did not outlive the local autorelease pool. specifically, the view would either never be displayed, or the controller would not control it while it's displayed (if the vc were destroyed before the local autorelease pool). the frameworks may also create autorelease pools.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `m_tabbarController` with retain kind of property.

Now, modify your code as below:

```
TabbarController *temp = [[TabbarController alloc] init];

self.m_tabbarController = temp;

[temp release];
```

Also, release `m_tabbarController` into `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.m_tabbarController = nil;
TabbarController *tempController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];
self.m_tabbarController = tempController;
[tempController release];
tempController = nil;
```

Answer (score -1):

`[self.m_tabbarController release];` will release `m_tabbarController` not `self` so

```
if(self.m_tabbarController != nil)
    {
      [self.m_tabbarController release];    
    }
self.m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];
```

is absolutely fine

Comment: There's a very good chance that this will result in a memory leak.

Comment: @omz he might have declared `@property` as `assign`,. so you can guess that it is `retain` if he has written `self.m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];` then I assume that he is not retaing it...

Comment: I don't see the point of declaring a property as `assign` but then retaining its value.

Comment: neither i see it as `retain`. so I don't know who has down voted he must have a valid reason.

Comment: Because it's not clear from the question whether the property is declared as `assign` or `retain`, I said there's a _very good chance_ of a memory leak, not that there will definitely be one. If the property is retained, this will definitely leak. If it is not, you're still doing it wrong, because when you set a property, you should never have to worry about releasing the previously-assigned object first, _especially_ if the property claims to not be retained.

Comment: that's a convention that you are talking about but it's not `must`.. anyways my answer was about his problem not about memory management